# How to get Return Value to use in Controller

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, get, return

this is my function in **model.php**

```
function add_user($data, $table){
        $this->db->trans_start();
        $insert_id = $this->db->insert($table, $data);
        $this->db->insert_id();
        $this->db->trans_complete();

        return $insert_id;
    }
```

how to get the value of $insert_id in other function
*Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this in controller

```
$inserted_id  = $this->Add_user_model->add_user($data, $table);
```

documentation : https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html#id4

Answer (score 0):

Once variables **$data**, **$table** declared, and function **add_user** is defined - you have to call this to make use of it. Try as follows:

`add_user($data, $table);`

Comment: when i call function ```add user``` its alwas return 1 not the last id